# Why do I get "cannot be accessed with an instance reference" when using teststring.Join but not teststring.Split? (c#)

Tags: c#

I'm learning c# and there is something I do not understand that I've been unable to find any help about online.

```
string[] = testarray = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
teststring = teststring.Join(" ", testarray);
```

This fails with the following error message:

> Member 'string.Join(string, params string[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

It does however work if I change to:

```
teststring = string.Join(" ", testarray);
```

If I however use the function Split as in:

```
teststring = teststring.Split(new char[] {' '});
```

I am no longer getting an error. I assume this has something to do with certain functions of the string class being static and some not, but how can I tell which function is static and which is not? (if this is the reason)

These enforced calling techniques between static / non-static sure is something to get used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct on the reason; `String.Join` is static but `String.Split` is not.

> I am no longer getting an error. I assume this has something to do with certain functions of the string class being static and some not, but how can I tell which function is static and which is not? (if this is the reason)

You could look at the MSDN docs.

For example, on the page for [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx), there is an `S` next to the purple box for each method; this indicates that the method is declared as `static`. Additionally, if you click on a particular overload you'll see the method declared as `static`. For example,

```
public static string Join(
string separator,
IEnumerable<string> values
)
```

However, for [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), there is no `S` next to the purple box for each method. For none of the particular overloads is the method declared as `static`. For example

```
public string[] Split(
params char[] separator
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can look at MSDN's documentation for the [`String` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx) for a list of all available methods. Static methods have an orange "S" icon next to them, while instance methods do not, e.g.:

[image]

When thinking about the difference between static and instance methods, think about whether the functionality of that method depends on a particular instance of the class.
If the answer is yes, then it's likely to be implemented as an instance method; and if not, it's likely to be a static method.
For example, the `Split` method separates a specific instance of the `String` class (the string from which it is called) into an array.
In contrast, the `Join` method is like a utility method, which can be called upon to combine an array separated by a string -- without first creating an instance of the `String` class in order to call it.

Comment: You need an instance of `string` to serve as the joining string. So one could imagine `String.Join` not being static but instead being an instance method and invoked as `",".Join(strings)`.

Comment: @Jason That's true, although if join were implemented as an instance method it seems like it would make more sense for it to be defined on the array of values being joined, rather than the separator.

Answer (score 4):

This is because Join is a static method on string. static methods are always called using the class name, not the name of a variable for an instance of that class.

Comment: I was on the right track then, how can I tell if a function is static or not of say string?

Comment: You haven't answered the full question.

Answer (score 2):

Join is a static method on the String class, whereas Split is an instance method. To find out which is which, right click on String and Go To Definintion. This will show you the definition of the class (with method declarations, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I would assume its because the method is not directly related to the `String` reference in any way and in order to avoid any confusion they made it a static method of `String` instead, whereas Split is directly related as you're splitting that particular `String` instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect Answer.. It Works well..

A static member function does not belong to a specific instance of a class but rather to the class type itself. As a result, when you are attempting to access it for a specific instance, the compiler is not allowing this.

To call the function correctly, you would have to write

classname.methodname(parameter)

rather than
Classname cl=new Classname();
cl.methodname(parameter);

or remove the static modified.

For more Please Refer this..
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=438550