# Cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “cannot be accessed with an instance reference” when using teststring.Join but not teststring.Split? (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368295/why-do-i-get-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-reference-when-using-teststri)

I am not sure what is wrong with the code. I tried googling but didn't got relevant info.

This is my for loop.

```
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    slide.Move(s, i, j); // this is the problem. 
                }
            }
```

and this is my move function. According to me I think I'm calling the function the way it is suppose to but I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I am fairly new the language.

```
         protected static void Move(string s, int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in Move function");
        try
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol + x, origRow + y);
            Console.Write(s);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_SIZE; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DEFAULT_SIZE; ++j)
            {
                    Console.Write("#");
                    Console.Write("\r{0}%   ", i,j);
                    //Console.WriteLine(slider[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Move` is a staic method so you can call it using `ClassName.Move`.

So, you have 2 options here.

1. Change `slide.Move(s, i, j);` to use the class name, not an instance variable. For example, if the class name `Slide` then you should use `Slide.Move(s, i, j);`.
2. Change `Move` to be an instance method.

I think option 2 is the way to go. As Jon Skeet pointed out. It make more sense that `Move` should be an instance method.

Comment: ... or make the `Move` method an instance method, of course. It doesn't *look* like it should be static.

Comment: The for loop is in main.and the Move function is in the class. So should I still use that with the name of the class rather than the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

> protected static void Move(string s, int x, int y)

static members belong to the class not an instance of the class. To access them, you precede them with the name of the class

```
[ClassName].Move(s, x, y);  //Slide.Move(x, y, z); assuming your class name is Slide
```

To use it like that you need to remove the static modifier

```
protected void Move(string s, int x, int y)
```